# Liferay Service Builder like tools

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay

I am new to Java EE but I worked on liferay framework. For my new assignment I need to use database. In liferay if we just add a table name/structure in service.xml then it creates necessary framework.

Are there any tools/frameworks that create APIs like liferay service builder creates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Minuteproject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/) provides reverse-engineering starting from the database for couples of technologies (backend and front-end)
If you come from Liferay, I advise you to check [minuteproject 4 Openxava](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/OpenXava), that generates CRUD from database and also liferay portlets.
You can also check among 15+ target technologies and [run demo](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Demos)